# SQL Create a midweek week-ending date without using a joining lookup table

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm wondering if it is possible to build a ORACLE SQL FUNCTION to return a mid-week date rather than using a joining table.

The week ends on a Wednesday so if we had date of Friday 5th Jan then the week ending date would be the following Wednesday 10/01/2018

```
MON 1ST JAN - 03/01/18
TUES 2ND JAN - 03/01/18
WED 3RD JAN - 03/01/18
THURS 4TH JAN - 10/01/18
FRI 5TH JAN - 10/01/18
SAT 6TH JAN - 10/01/18
SUN 7TH JAN - 10/01/18
MON 8TH JAN - 10/01/18
TUES 9TH JAN - 10/01/18
WED 10TH JAN - 10/01/18
THURS 11TH JAN - 17/01/18
```

The reason I'm investigating the function route is to future proof the process so I do not have maintain a second lookup table & get rid of unnecessary joins.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to google a work around

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY('25-JAN-2018 00.00', 'WEDNESDAY')FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: +1 for me. It's better to avoid writing dates in that way. ANSI format could be a better way, not depending on the language (`date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`)

Comment: For a Wednesday this gives you the next Wednesday, so you'd have to apply this on date - 1. A big disadvantage of this function is that it is session dependent. It only works for sessions set to English. I'd rather go with Aleksejs solution for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like the following:

```
select d, 
       case
            when trunc(d, 'IW') +2 >= d
                then trunc(d, 'IW') +2
                else trunc(d, 'IW') +9
       end as next_wed
from (
        select date '2018-01-01' + level -1 as d
        from dual
        connect by level <= 11
     )
```

This gets the monday of the week in which your date is contained and then adds 2 or 9 depending on the fact that adding 2 gives a day before the inut date or not.

Another way could be by checking if the input date is a before or after the wednesday in its week:

```
case when to_char(d, 'D') <= 3
     then trunc(d, 'IW') +2
     else trunc(d, 'IW') +9
end as next_wed
```